# Using SSH2 and SFTPStream to stream file from server to AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sftp

I'm trying to use the [ssh2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2) module to take a file from a server and add it to an S3 bucket in AWS. I would like to be able to stream the file so that I don't have to have it in memory. I tried the following:

```
const Client = require('ssh2').Client;
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new aws.S3();

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {

    let connSettings = {
        host: event.serverHost,
        port: event.port,
        username: event.username,
        password: event.password
    };

    let conn = new Client();
    conn.on('ready', function() {

        conn.sftp(true, function(err, sftp) {

            if (err) throw err;

            let stream = sftp.createReadStream(filename);
            let putParams = {
                Bucket: s3Bucket,
                Key: s3Key,
                Body: stream
            };

            s3.putObject(putParams, function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;

                console.log("Uploaded!");
            });     
        });
    }).connect(connSettings);

};
```

However, the method `sftp.createReadStream(filename)` is looking at my local directory and not the server. Which other than that, it works.

Is there a way I can stream a file from a server to S3?

I know I could use the [sftp.fastGet](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2-streams/blob/master/SFTPStream.md) method to download the file from the server, save it locally, and then upload it to S3. But I would prefer not to have to save the file locally. The s3 SDK accepts a stream, so it would be much more convenient to just stream it.

**UPDATE**: the method `sftp.createReadStream(filename)` is correctly reading from the server and not locally. It is the `s3.putObject` method that is for some reason trying to get the file locally even though I'm giving it a stream.

Comment: where is `sftp` defined?

Comment: @DanielA.White, I updated with a bit more code.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the method `s3.putObject` is looking for the file locally even though I give it a stream. The stream contains the path from the server, but for whatever reason, when the method `s3.putObject` method is reading the stream, it tries reading the file locally.

I fixed this by instead using the `s3.upload` method.

```
s3.upload(putParams, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log("Uploaded!");
});
```